# Testing correlation between two variables when there are other variables involved

Tags: regression, correlation, statistical-significance

I want to see if there is any correlation between number of pages in a paper and the citation it receives. If I just plot number of pages vs number of citations of a paper, I might get a correlation, but that might be wrong, because there are other variables such as age of the paper, venue impact factor etc. How to get around this problem? If I do a multiple regression with some known variables and report the coefficient for my variable, is that sufficient?

Comment: "test" $\neq$ "report"; do you mean "test the coefficient for my variable"? Or are you more worried about measurement of the effect than testing it?

Comment: at this moment, i want to see if there is any significant correlation. so i guess i am more focused on the test part.

Comment: Well, multiple regression is what I'd do. If you specifically want a correlation that accounts for other variables you might calculate a partial correlation.

Comment: as the predictor variables do not follow normal distribution, should i use linear multiple regression or something like logistic regressiom?

Comment: Why would the predictors need to be normal for anything?

Comment: Sorry, I think I was confused. The outcome variable is not continuous, so I don't think multiple regression would be a wise decision here.

Comment: If it's a count, one could use GLMs instead, such as Poisson regression.

Comment: I didn't know about Poisson regression before. Thanks for mentioning that. The wikipedia entry says that "events must be independent in the sense that the arrival of one call will not make another more or less likely", but I think that's not true for citations.

Comment: Yes, such dependence would probably lead to overdispersion, which suggests a negative binomial model might do better. [Note that this lack of independence would *also* affect inference on correlation, multiple linear regression, logistic regression and so on ... and yet that didn't seem to worry you. Why is it particularly worrying you for Poisson regression if it didn't concern you before?]

Comment: logistic regression is giving me what is P(Y=0|X=x) or P(Y=1|X=x) assuming the underlying distribution is a logit function, isn't it? How the dependence on previous values of y come into picture?

Comment: Logistic regression - as with any other GLM, including multiple regression - assumes the observations are independent. The effect will impact the variation around the model, impacting confidence intervals and hypothesis tests.